cannot get properties of undefined reading 'remove points' in highcharts
I am new to highcharts and I couldn't find any proper examples to implement my scenario of showing and hiding series in high charts based on user actions in react . Implemented highcharts in React and TS
const options = useMemo(() => {
  return {
    
 

    yAxis: [
      {
        opposite: false,
        title: {
          text: ' ',
        },
      },
      {
        opposite: false,
      },
      {
        opposite: false,
      },
    ],
   

    tooltip: {
      pointFormat:
        '<span style="fontSize:12px; fontWeight:200 ">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
      valueDecimals: 0,
      split: false,
      shared: true,
    },

    series: [
      {
        id: 'aumWithPayouts',
        yAxis: 0,
        name: 'Holding anum + payouts',
        visible: selectedReference?.symbol ? false : true,
        data: selectedReference?.symbol ? [] : netWorthWithPayouts,
        color: colors.profitBorder,
        type: 'line',
      },

      {
        name: 'Holding anum',
        color: colors.lossBorder,
        threshold: dynamicStartingValueRef.current,
        yAxis: 0,
        visible: selectedReference?.symbol ? false : true,
        data: selectedReference?.symbol ? [] : netWorth,
        type: 'areaspline',

        zones: startingValueRef.current
          ? [
              {
                value: startingValueRef.current, // for loss
                color: selectedReference?.symbol
                  ? colors.profitBorder
                  : colors.lossBorder,

                fillColor: {
                  linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 1,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 0,
                  },
                  stops: [
                    [0, colors.lossFill],
                    [1, '#fff'],
                  ],
                },
              },
              {
                color: colors.profitBorder, // for profit
                fillColor: {
                  linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 1,
                  },
                  stops: [
                    [0, colors.profitFill],
                    [1, '#fff'],
                  ],
                },
              },
            ]
          : undefined,
      },
      {
        type: 'flags',
        name: 'Dividends',
        yAxis: 0,
        zIndex: 2,

        visible: selectedReference?.symbol ? false : true,
        data: selectedReference?.symbol ? [] : dividends,

        onSeries: 'aumWithPayouts',
        shape: 'squarepin',
        color: '#c5c5c5',
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2,
          pointFormat:
            '<span style="fontSize:12px; fontWeight:200 ">{series.name}</span>: Rs{point.text}  <br/>',
        },
      },

      {
        name: selectedReference?.symbol || 'Index',

        yAxis: 1,
        type: 'line',
        visible: selectedReference?.symbol ? true : false,
        data: selectedReference?.symbol ? reference : [],

        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2,
          valueSuffix: '%',
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Daily PNL',
        yAxis: 1,
        type: 'line',
        visible: selectedReference?.symbol ? true : false,
        data: selectedReference?.symbol ? netWorth : [],
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: '%',
        },
      },
    ],
  };
}, [
  getDynamicStartingValue,
  netWorthWithPayouts,
  selectedReference?.symbol,
  netWorth,
  reference,

  dividends,
]);

return (
  <>
    <HighchartsReact
      constructorType={'stockChart'}
      highcharts={Highcharts}
      options={options}
      oneToOne={true}
    />
  </>
);

how my chart looks on first render

how my chart displays last two series when i click on add comparison button

I am displaying series in high charts based on user actions. I show the first three series on first render. After a user action, I display the last two series , and when the user wants to view the data of first three series again. I hide the last two series to show the first three and this is where I get the Error , cannot read properties of undefined reading 'remove points'
I do not get this error if I comment out the 'flags' series
